# Bucle jstl mostrando 3 artículos de una lista

Tags: jsp, jstl

estoy intentando recorrer una lista de 8 artículos en concreto.
Necesitaría mostrar los tres primeros, pero no me ha quedado muy claro como hacerlo.

Agradezco la ayuda.

```
<c:forEach begin="0" step="1" end="3" items="${Articulos}">
                <div>${item.idArticulo}</div>
                <a class="destacado my-2" style="word-break: break-word;" 
                  href="${item.url}">${item.nombre}</a> 
</c:forEach>
```

Se que no esta bien pero por lo menos sirve para explicar mi duda.

En la lista de artículos, tengo 8 artículos quiero que me muestre solo 3 articulos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando `item` como variable para referirte al artículo en cada iteración, pero no la has declarado, creo que es lo único que te falta:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" step="1" end="2" items="${Articulos}" var="item">
    <div>${item.idArticulo}</div>
    <a class="destacado my-2" style="word-break: break-word;" 
                  href="${item.url}">${item.nombre}</a> 
</c:forEach>
```

Un detalle: el índice empieza en 0 y `end` indica el límite de manera inclusiva, así que para mostrar los tres primeros elementos necesitas ponerlo a 2, no a 3

Comment: Lo de el item, creo que me lo coge sin que ponga el "item." el problema es que lo que declaro como articulo es una lista que viene desde el servlet, y tiene diferentes variables dentro, id, nombre.. etc. Entonces quiero ver 3 de esos artículos de la lista. Es decir recorrer la lista una vez y de los 8 resultados coger los 3 primeros.

Comment: Cierto no me había fijado que si le pongo 2 desde el 0 son 3. Gracias